# Joining MongoDB collections with $in operator in MongoShell using array

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections: users and network that I'm trying to join:

```
users has user_id, user_name (example: 101, Bob 102, Alice, 103, Charlie)    
network has user_id1, user_id2 (example 101, 103)
```

Conceptually, Charlie (103) follows Bob (101) on Twitter. (Alice has followers too, but she doesn't like to talk about them.)

This mongo code works in the mongo shell (Actual user_ids shown):

```
db.users.find( { user_id : { $in: [53760842,64188597,140479494] } } , { user_name: 1 } )
```

{ "user_name" : "lizgaule" }
{ "user_name" : "taella" }

This does not:

```
var cur = db.network.find( {user_id1 : 14230524}, {_id:0, user_id2:1} )  
var arr = cur.toArray();  
db.users.find( { user_id: { $in: arr } } , { user_name: 1 } )
```

I suspect the array arr is not in the right format. it contains:
        {
                "user_id2" : 64188597
        },
        {
                "user_id2" : 53760842
        }

**Question What code do I need to make this work?**

Comment: I've also tried putting arr in brackets, ala [arr] but this did not work either.

Comment: In python, I suspect I would "unzip" the array arr and only use a list of the second element, but haven't figured out if that can be done in MongoDB. Be kind, I've only been using mongo to 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [.map()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) the results of your first query. This can be used to extract the relevant values. In your case I believe that's `user_id2`:

```
var arr = db.network.find( {user_id1 : 14230524}, {_id:0, user_id2:1} ).map(function(doc){
  return doc.user_id2;
}) ;  
db.users.find( { user_id: { $in: arr } } , { user_name: 1 } );
```

Comment: Perfect! That solved the problem. Thanks for helping me resolve this.